# FFMPEG: Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0.Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, mpd, dash.js

I'm using FFMPEG to connect an RTSP and create video files on the fly that can be viewed in a mpeg-dash compatible browser using HTML5 video element and dash.js

ffmpeg to connect to your ip camera

> ffmpeg -i rtsp://194.168.26.234:554 -r 64k -an -c:v copy -b:v 2000k
> -fflags nobuffer -f dash -window_size 4 -extra_window_size 0 -min_seg_duration 2000000 -remove_at_exit 1 ..\www\manifest.mpd

When I Run the command,it streaming properly but in the middle I'm getting error on Timestamps and also in Non-monotonous DTS. And also it was 3-15 sec delay  Here My error,

> [dash @ 000000d62f752f20] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream
> 0. This is  deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timest amps properly
> [dash @ 000000d62f752f20] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0;
> previous: 0, current: 0;changing to 1. This may result in incorrect
> timestamps in the output file.
>
> [mp4 @ 000000d6302824e0] Application provided duration: -64 /
> timestamp: 1275009  is out of range for mov/mp4 format
>
> frame=  513 fps= 34 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:20.40 bitrate=N/A
> speed=1.35x frame=  527 fps= 34 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:20.96
> bitrate=N/A speed=1.34x
>
> [dash @ 000000d62f752f20] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 134 1505, current: 1341505; changing to 1341506. This may result in incorrect timest amps in the output file.

Comment: I don't know about the timestamps, but you can fix the DTS errors by adding `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` before your `-i`, read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50946106/138541