# Youtube live streaming

Tags: ffmpeg

Everyone
I use the Logitech C920R to distribute live to Youtube.

The commands are as follows.

```
#! / bin / sh
YOUTUBE_URL = "rtmp: //a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
KEY = "xxxx-yyyy-zzzz"
v4l2 - ctl --device = / dev / video0 - set - fmt - video = width = 1280, height = 720
ffmpeg - ar 44100 - ac 2 - f alsa - i hw: 1,0 - f v 4 l 2 - codec: v h 264 - framerate 30 - video-- size 1280 x 720 --itsoffset 0.5 \
-i / dev / video0 - copyyinkf - codec: v copy - codec: a aac - ab 128 k - g 10 - strict experimental \
-f flv $ YOUTUBE_URL / $ KEY
1> / dev / null 2> / dev / null &
```

When I run this command, I get the following message.

```
[alsa @ 0xbbe770] ALSA buffer xrun.
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xbc92d0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[alsa @ 0xbbe770] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[flv @ 0xc3d940] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 500, current: 329; changing to 500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xc3d940] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 500, current: 361; changing to 500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xc3d940] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 500, current: 393; changing to 500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xc3d940] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 500, current: 429; changing to 500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xc3d940] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 500, current: 461; changing to 500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xc3d940] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 500, current: 497; changing to 500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame= 1112 fps= 31 q=-1.0 size=   14271kB time=00:00:42.16 bitrate=2772.7kbits/s speed=1.18x
```

What is this message telling me?

Is there anything to improve?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the `DTS` errors by adding `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` before your camera input, same goes for the `thread_queue_size` error, add `-thread_queue_size 512` before `-i`.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -thread_queue_size 512 -i /dev/video0 -c copy test.mp4
```

---

**A brief explanation from [Jann](https://superuser.com/questions/474004/mjpeg-recording-with-ffmpeg-preserving-time-information#comment710672_580461)**

> This forces FFMPEG (a hack really) to use the recording SYSTEM's
>   timestamp instead of trying to compute the time of the movie depending
>   on the number of fps it detects. FPS detection is notoriously
>   inaccurate, for instance.
>
> As FFMPEG freely admits when it gives this
>   error: `Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate`.
>
> This also enables the `-t` flag (duration) to be real-time as well, instead of
>   also being dependent on the fps calculation.